# Can't manage to center the loader

Tags: html, css

I'm using a loader in my application, but I can't manage to properly centre it.

As you are going to see it's slightly moved to left side of the screen.

Here's the fiddle: [Loader](https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/1/)

Here's the HTML code:

```
  <div class="loader">
      <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
      <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
      <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
  </div>
```

Here's the SCSS code:

```
.loader-graph-default{
      background-color: black;
      display: none;
  }

  .loader-graph-loading{
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .loader {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

    &__hexagon {
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      transform: rotate(30deg);
      animation: fade 1s infinite;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      background: white;  

      &--value {
          background: #009ECB;
      }

      &:first-of-type {
        top: 20px;
        left: -12px;
        animation-delay: .4s;
      }

      &:last-of-type {
        top: 20px;
        left: 12px;
        animation-delay: .2s;
      }

      &:before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
        height:20px;
        background: inherit;
        transform: rotate(-62deg);
      }

      &:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
        height: 20px;
        background: inherit;
        transform: rotate(62deg);
      }
    }
  }

  @keyframes fade{
    0%{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    50%{
      opacity: .1;
    }

    100%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

If you go to the fiddle and you inspect the div with the class "loader" you can see that it's not centred.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a basic remark, your loader is cool, but it would be far easier to handle if you just made a GIF from it (here, it is complex and consumes some CPU just for that, it feels quite overkill just for that). The center problem comes from the positioning, as soon as you change the position attribute, you break the HTML flow.

Comment: Why not make use of [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=b)?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/7/

Comment: Pls check this https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/9/

Comment: @ankitapatel Still not centred! Check Ankita's fiddle!

Comment: 1 min in fiddle there is some issue.

Comment: @ste pls check this https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/9/

Comment: @ste you're welcome. Also check out AwsmeSandy's answer, seems like he found a good way too.

Comment: &__hexagon { ... margin: 5px 5px 5px 23px;....} also you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `loader` width `60px` to `48px` to resolve this. check updated snippet below..

```css
.loader-graph-default {
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
}
.loader-graph-loading {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.loader {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    left: 12px;
}
.loader__hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    animation: fade 1s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    background: white;
}
.loader__hexagon--value {
    background: #009ECB;
}
.loader__hexagon:first-of-type {
    top: 20px;
    left: -12px;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.loader__hexagon:last-of-type {
    top: 20px;
    left: 12px;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.loader__hexagon:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    background: inherit;
    transform: rotate(-62deg);
}
.loader__hexagon:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    background: inherit;
    transform: rotate(62deg);
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
  <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
  <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you rotate a div, of course it changes it centre point, so i just repositioned it.

```css
.loader-graph-default{
      background-color: black;
      display: none;
  }

  .loader-graph-loading{
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 100;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .loader {
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;

    &__hexagon {
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      transform: rotate(30deg);
      animation: fade 1s infinite;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      /*background: $uiColor;*/
      background: white;

      /*
      &--carbon {
        background: $carbon;
      }

      &--value {
        background: $value;
      }

      &--research {
        background: $research;
      }

      &--quality {
        background: $quality;
      }
      */
      
      &--value {
          background: #009ECB;
      }

      &:first-of-type {
    top: 20px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 3px;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      &:last-of-type {
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    margin-left: 6px;
      }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
      &:before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
        height:20px;
        background: inherit;
        transform: rotate(-62deg);
      }

      &:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
        height: 20px;
        background: inherit;
        transform: rotate(62deg);
      }
    }
  }

  @keyframes fade{
    0%{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    50%{
      opacity: .1;
    }

    100%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
          <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
          <div class="loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value"></div>
      </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have added left:-12px to the first of div with class "loader__hexagon loader__hexagon--value", which shifts the whole block to the left by -12px.

Also the width of the Loader is not 60px.
The style should be as given below :

```
.loader__hexagon:first-of-type {
top: 20px;
animation-delay: 0.4s;}
```

Add a style for second child:

```
.loader__hexagon:nth-child(2) {
   left: 12px; }
```

Edit style of third child:

```
.loader__hexagon:last-of-type {
    top: 20px;
    left: 23px;
    animation-delay: 0.2s; }
```

Reduce the width of the loader to 45px:

```
.loader {
   background: none;
   position: relative;
   width: 45px;
   height: 60px;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute positioning on your hexagons, that's why they are not centered, try a different approach such as display: inline-block with adjusted margins (some space inbetween) for bottom hexagons.

```
  &__hexagon {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  &:first-of-type {
    display: block;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  &:last-of-type {
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0d5ovms/11/)